# Laravel Join Query return Invalid Object Name

Tags: laravel

I have two Models (Color and ColorFamily Table).I would like to join two table.When I join Second Table (ColorFamily),its shows an error message "Invalid Object Name ColorFamily".If I use to Join First Table then its shows an error message "Invalid Object Name Color".

Note:-

If I use Individual Query (Select Query) without join ,then the records is showing,that means both the tables are available...

I have check with google but can not find the solution.....

```
Color Models:-



 <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Color extends Model
    {
    protected $primaryKey = 'ColorId';
  protected $table = 'Common_Ref_Color';
  public $timestamps = false;

}

ColorFamily Models:-

<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ColorFamily extends Model
{
  protected $primaryKey = 'ColorFamilyId';
  protected $table = 'Common_Ref_ColorFamily';
  public $timestamps = false;

}

Controller:-
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\ColorFamily;
use App\Models\Color;

class ColorController extends Controller
{
    public function Index()
    {        
         $Data = Color::select ('ColorId','ColorName','ColorCode','ColorShortCode')
            ->join('ColorFamily','ColorFamilyId','=','Color.ColorFamilyId')
            ->get();  
        return $Data;  



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code:

```
class ColorController extends Controller {
        public function Index()
        {        
             $Data = DB::table('Color')
                ->select ('ColorId','ColorName','ColorCode','ColorShortCode')
                ->join('ColorFamily','ColorFamily.ColorFamilyId','=','Color.ColorFamilyId')
                ->get();  
            return $Data;                 

        }       
}
```

I think that you need to add joined table name inside join

('***ColorFamily***.ColorFamilyId','=','Color.ColorFamilyId')

Comment: No,I am not going to use "DB",instead of that I am going to use "Model" .In my Code Color is Model Name and "Common_Ref_Color" is TableName

Comment: @MuhammedIsmail That's fine. Can you try to replace join() clause with the one I wrote?

Comment: still I have the same issue.see the code below                      public function Index()
    {       
        
        $Data = Color::select ('ColorId','ColorName','ColorCode','ColorShortCode')
        ->join('ColorFamily.ColorFamilyId','=','Color.ColorFamilyId')
        ->get();  
        return $Data;  
        
                 
    }

Comment: Can you define relationships inside models? With defined relationships in models, you don't need that join

Comment: I was thinking that join is applicable only for DB facade but I found somewhere join() example with Model so I am not 100% sure